# Drag Formula change Row reference instead of Column Excel

Tags: excel, formula

I have a database of things associated with people who like them, as exampled below:

**THIS SHEET NAME IS SHEET 1**

[image: Image of Current Database]

In another sheet, I am attempting to sort the things by each person who likes them.

In the second sheet, I need to check to make sure the cell is not blank (because another user input may add additional people). If the cell has a persons name in it, I need to cycle through all of the things in the database to see if that person's name appears next to it.

If it does, then I want it to return all of their favorite things, like is shown in GREEN below:

**THIS SHEET NAME IS SHEET 2**
[image: Image of Database After Function]

I know I need to use the OFFSET function, but as I have it written right now, it is not working. Any help is much appreciated it!

My function is below. This would be a function for B2 in SHEET 2. I want to be able to drag this function to the right (from B2 to F2) and have the output like shown in the green above.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(OFFSET(sheet1!$B$2:$F$2, 0, COLUMN()-2) $A$2), OFFSET(sheet1!A2, 0, COLUMN() -2), " ")
```

I am currently getting an error message that I have too few arguments. However, I imagine that there is something else that is wrong with what I am trying to do... any help is MUCH much appreciated

SHEET 1 DATA:

```
Things  People Who Like The Thing                       
Potatoes    Person 3    Person 6                    
Cats    Person 1    Person 4    Person 6                
Mice    Person 2    Person 6                    
Green   Person 2    Person 6                    
Wine    Person 1    Person 5    Person 6                
Chicken Person 1    Person 6                    
Dogs    Person 1    Person 4    Person 6                
Flowers Person 2    Person 5    Person 6                
Chair   Person 3    Person 6                    
Shirts  Person 4    Person 6
```

SHEET 2 (UNSOLVED) DATA:

```
    Favorite Things                                 
Person 1                                        
Person 2                                        
Person 3                                        
Person 4                                        
Person 5                                        
Person 6
```

Comment: Could you post at least the first sheet as data and not a photo so we do not need to retype the data just to test the formula?

Comment: I apologize, I am not sure how to post the excel sheet as data

Comment: Copy then paste directly into the original post using edit.  Then highlight the data and press ctrl-k

Comment: Should be added- thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the SMALL(IF()) style formula.

If you have 2010 or later then it can be done easily with the AGGREGATE() Function:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$11,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW(Sheet1!$B$2:$D$11)-1)/(Sheet1!$B$2:$D$11=$A2),COLUMN(A:A))),"")
```

So what these formulas do is they use the SMALL() formula.  The small formula is set up this way `SMALL(Range,k)`.  `k` is the instance, as in if k was 3 then it would return the 3rd smallest.

Since we use the `COLUMN(A:A)` as our `k` the number returned by `COLUMN(A:A)` will increase by one each time it is filled to the right. Thus giving us a list of the 1st, then the 2nd then the 3rd...

It is this number that is passed to the INDEX.

If you do not then use this array formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$11,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$B$2:$D$11=$A2,(ROW(Sheet1!$B$2:$D$11)-1)),COLUMN(A:A))),"")
```

being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when leaving edit mode instead of Enter.  If done correctly the excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly! I have never worked with arrays before, so I appreciate your help a ton.

Comment: You seem to be having a monopoly on answers to array formula questions Scott. Might have to contact the FTC...